# ASIDownloadCache security

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am caching some data using `ASIDownloadCache` as shown below.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
        [request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
        [request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
        [request setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*30]; // Cache for 30 days, this will change to a db version check.
        [request setDelegate:self]; // this calls the delegate function requestFinished
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

I was wondering how secure that data was? for instance I know that someone with a jailbroken phone can access coredata sotrage.. but what about `ASIDownloadCache`? what would someone need to do to get to it? how can I protect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to jailbreak to access it, see:

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

If you want to protect it, you'll need to encrypt it, and you will have to do this yourself or modify ASIDownloadCache to do it.

Given the decryption key will need to be present in your application this would really just be obfuscation though.